# ToolTip content is lost when it exceeds the monitor display

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, jface, rcp

I have a class that extends ColumnViewerToolTipSupport. Problem here is when the tooltip content is huge and tend to exceed the monitor display area, the content is simply lost. There is no way to see the lost content by scrolling or any other actions.

I have tried `setRespectDisplayBounds(true)` as well as `setRespectMonitorBounds(true)`. Still no impact.

Can I get some help here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an eclipse bug :https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345288
Not sure whether it is resolved already in recent versions.